# postgres random text in jsonb column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, random, sql-update

Following is the query I'm using to scrub some fields in the JSONB column. I'm trying to radomize the first and last name so would like to use something like md5(random()::text) as values.

```
update people set
data = to_jsonb(data) || '{"firstName": "random_text", "lastName": "random_text"}'
where id = 'b3c09005-7afb-4ad6-922d-76078875e59e';
```

I tried replacing "random_text" with md5(...) but I get an error "DETAIL:  Token "md5" is invalid.". I also tried using || to concat but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should concatenate the string with your random function and then cast it to `jsonb` -

```
select ('{"firstName":"' ||  md5(random()::text) || '", "lastName":"' || md5(random()::text) ||'"}')::jsonb
```

Above will create a `jsonb` object with random first and last name.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a json builder function to generate the json object:

```
update people set
data = data || jsonb_build_object(
    'firstName', md5(random()::text), 
    'lastName',  md5(random()::text)
)
where id = 'b3c09005-7afb-4ad6-922d-76078875e59e';
```

It seems like `data` is of datatype `JSONB`. If so, there is not need to use `to_jsonb()` on it; `||` is sufficient.